# React Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to render the data from my database get this instead Failed to compile.

./src/components/list-pets.component.js
  Line 38:5:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.enter code here

Here is my code from the trouble component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

export default class ListPets extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
          pets: []
        };

    }


    componentDidMount = () => {
      this.getPets();
    };    


    getPets = () => {  
    axios.get('http://localhost:5000/pets')
      .then((response) => {
        const data = response.data;
        this.setState({ pets: data });
        console.log('Data has been received!');
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
}

displayPet = (pets) => {

  if (!pets.length) return null;

  return pets.map((pet, index) => {
    <div key={index}>
      <h3>{pet.name}</h3>
      <p>{pet.species}</p>
    </div>
  });


};
```

render() {

```
console.log('State: ', this.state);

return (

  <div className='adopt'>
    {this.displayPet(this.state.pets)}

  </div>
```

)
}
}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to return a value at each `pets.map` iteration, currently you’re returning undefined.

```
  return pets.map((pet, index) => {
    return (
      <div key={index}>
        <h3>{pet.name}</h3>
        <p>{pet.species}</p>
      </div>
    )
  });
```

Comment: Thanks that fixed the error, but I still can not get my data to render. The initial state for pets is an empty array, but when I console log the new state from the database it shows an empty string.

Comment: @JoshuaLipscomb it sounds like your server may not be returning the expected response. I'd suggest looking at the Network tab of your browser's Web Inspector to preview the server response and check if it's correct.

Answer (score -1):

You have to wait until fetching data is completed.
You should have to define the loading bar while fetching.

```
class App extends Component {
    constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
       pageData: {},
       loading: true
    }

    this.getData();
  }

  async getData(){
      const res = await fetch('/pageData.json');
      const data = await res.json();
      return this.setState({ 
      pageData: data, 
      loading: false 
   });
 }

 componentDidMount() {
    this.getData();
 }

 render() {
     const { loading, pageData } = this.state;
     if (loading){
          return <LoadingBar />
 }
 return (
  <div className="App">
    <Navbar />
  </div>
);
```

}
}

Comment: Ok, so I need to convert my list-pet component into a sync/await function and include a loading bar?